# T-SQL regular expression replace

Tags: sql, sql-server, regex, t-sql

I need to do a replacement of the string in SQL server. I know that t-sql does not completely support this regex replace feature, but we can use functions such as `PATINDEX` to do that.

Basically, what I need is to replace a string of URL start with **www** or **www[0-9]**, for example:

- www.123456.com => 123456.com
- www2.123456.com => 123456.com

I tried: `PATINDEX('(www[0-9]?)\.%',@url)`, but it does not match what I need. Does anyone know how to simply do this without a function CLR ?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can

```
with t(f) as (
    select 'www.foo.com' union
    select 'www9.bar.com' union
    select 'wwwz.quz.com' union
    select 'mail.xxx.com'
)
select 
    case when patindex('www.%', f) + patindex('www[0-9].%', f) = 0 then f else substring(f, 1 + charindex('.', f), len(f)) end
from t
```

For

```
(No column name)
mail.xxx.com
foo.com
bar.com
wwwz.quz.com
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `Stuff()` and `CharIndex()` functions:

```
Select stuff(url ,1, charindex('.', url), '') newUrl
From t
```

**[Fiddle demo 1](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/720d3/5)**

As per comments, you could do another check with a `CASE` expression:

```
select case when charindex('.', url, charindex('.', url)+ 1) > 0
            then stuff(url ,1,charindex('.', url),'') 
            else url
       end newUrl
from t
```

**[Fiddle demo 2](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/f98f7/2)**

Or if you need to check for the first 3 characters for www;

```
select case when left(url,3) = 'www'
            then stuff(url ,1,charindex('.', url),'') 
            else url
       end newUrl
from t
```

**[Fiddle demo 3](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/f98f7/4)**

Comment: No, this is not what I really need, because not all the url starts with **www**, if url is like **abc.com**, I need to keep as it is.

Comment: You can easily use a `Case expression` to do that.